# Assigning variables in switch and cases

Tags: c#, scope

I've been trying to assign a value to a variable and then use the same variable and value outside of this switch/case statement.

It says that the variable outside of the `switch` statement is not defined locally, and was wondering if it is possible to make this variable global.

Here is my code so far:

```
bool play;
string choice;
string guess;
int intChoice;
int intguess;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("1: New game\n2:quit");
    choice = Console.ReadLine();
    intChoice = Convert.ToInt32(choice);
    switch (intChoice)
    {
        case 1:
            play = true;
            break;

        case 2:
            play = false;
            break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(play);
```

*(please note that I know that I can use if statements but I want to know how switches and cases work!)*

Comment: *"says that the variable outside of the switch statement is not defined locally"* -- does the compiler trouble to say which variable is not defined locally?

Comment: I wouldnt use a switch _or_ an if statement for this.  If you are trying to learn switch I would suggest doing something that has more than 2 states.

Comment: @EdPlunkett havent seen you in a while, welcome back!

Comment: @maccettura Thank you. I've been spending my time at work working, of all things.

Comment: Patrick: In any case your switch might be better written as `play = (intChoice == 1);`

Comment: @EdPlunkett No, it's not.  That statement has wildly different semantics if the user enters any value other than 1 or 2.

Comment: ive not compiled the code so far as the debugger pics it up (microsft visual studio) and the debbuger seems to have no problem finding it, and also i will try to do another case thanks @maccettura !

Comment: The compiler is warning that a alue entered other than 1 or 2 means play won't be defined. Either use a default assignment before the switch or use a default clause in the switch to guarantee an assignment.

Comment: @Servy I think the point being made is that the OP only cares about two states, if the user hits 1, or if the user does not.  Thus my comment on `switch` not being the right approach for OP's code

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for that that makes sense and i will do that but now out of curiosity is there a way to make the variable accessable out side of the switch

Comment: @Servy See corrected comment.

Comment: @maccettura *My* point was that the OP *needs* to care about more than just those two states, because they aren't the only two possible states.  The OP needs to decide what they *want* to do for *all possible* states, not just two of them.

Comment: @patrick How can I answer that when you refuse to provide anything more than vague, tantalizing hints about what problem you're having? If you assign a value to `play` in a `case`, it'll retain that value. I have no idea what you're complaining about. My best guess is that the compiler is complaining because `play` is uninitialized, and you have no guarantee that it *will* be initialized before it's used. `intChoice` could be `3` or `65536`. If that's the problem, initialize `play` on declaration: `bool play = false;`. You should do that anyway, whatever your problem is.

Comment: @StuartLC Thank you that has fixed my problem!

Thanks everyone for helping me

Comment: @patrick And as Servy says, what happens if the user enters `3`? (I can tell you what happens if the user enters "LOL" -- can you tell me?)

Comment: @EdPlunkett  my problem has been solved but thanks for helping, and the program would not run as the play variable was not assigned a value out side of a case statement, but stuartLC had helped and told me why this was hapening

Comment: @EdPlunkett at that point in the code i did not have a default and that was causing the errors

Comment: @patrick Right. Try typing “LOL” at the prompt.

Comment: i will also add a try catch statement around the casting

Comment: This program is just a design i havnt started testing

Comment: if a null value is expected to be at some point the initial value of the variable then you should definitely change the type of variable to a nullable and do the proper validations before you print it out.

Comment: @SalvadorRuizGuevara also thanks i will change that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `play` will not be defined if the input is something other than `1` or `2`.  You want to make sure you handle every possible user input if you are going to allow it.   What if a user inputs `4`? What will happen? What about `Quit`?

You have a few options.  You can change your switch/case to an if/else block, which will be fine if you don't plan on extending the options much:

```
if (intChoice == 1)
    play = true;
else
    play = false;
```

You can also add a `default` statement to your switch like so:

```
switch (intChoice)
{
    case 1:
        play = true;
        break;

    case 2:
        play = false;
        break;

    default:
        //Handle invalid inputs
        play = false;
        break;
}
Console.WriteLine(play);
```

This gives you the option to add more `intChoice`s later without making it hard to extend.  There is some repeated code in this simple case.

You can also set `bool play = false;` at the very top of your code so that it is initialized for every case.

Comment: you can remove "break" from "case 2" and also remove "play=false" from "default". Or better just remove "case 2" entirely

Comment: You could, but it entirely depends on what the OP plans to do with the rest of the application.  This takes in the assumption that maybe OP would want to throw some error instead of just quitting on an invalid input.

Answer (score 5):

The problem will be that play may not be assigned if it falls through the switch statement (eg case 3:). either init the variable to bool play=false at start.. or add a default case to the switch statement

Answer (score 1):

The variable has not been initialized properly if it another case besides the 1 and 2 cases. What you need is a default case to initialize the variable in case anything else falls thru the switch. It is also good practice of using switch...case.

Another good practice would be defining the initial value of the variable so an exception does not happen.

Changing your variable scope from local to global (if in this case its scope is local to a greater scope than of the switch case) wont change anything. Since the scope only defines the 'life expectancy' of the variable.